# Migration error Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I have following model classes in my App called "`team_rooster`"

```
class Spieler(StructBlock):
    nummer = IntegerBlock(required=True)
    position = ChoiceBlock(choices=[
        ('th', 'TH'),
        ], icon='cup')

class TeamRooster(Page):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    spieler = StreamField([
        ('spieler', CardsBlock(Spieler(), icon="user")),
    ], default='', blank=True)

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('team_name', classname="col12"),
        StreamFieldPanel('spieler'),
    ]
```

and ill render it within `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import TeamRooster
# Create your views here.
def teams(request):
    teams = TeamRooster.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'team_rooster.html', { 'teams': teams})
```

and plus following `template`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  {% for team in teams %}
  <div class="row">
    <table border="2" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="5">{{team.team_name}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{team.spieler.nummer}}</td>
          <td>{{team.spieler.position}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When I do a migration, I get an error:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, home, sessions, taggit, team_rooster, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 169, in get_model
    return self.models[model_name.lower()]
KeyError: 'spieler'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 186, in handle
    changes = autodetector.changes(graph=executor.loader.graph)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\autodetector.py", line 47, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\autodetector.py", line 189, in _detect_changes
    self.generate_altered_fields()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\autodetector.py", line 911, in generate_altered_fields
    if old_field_dec != new_field_dec:
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailcore\blocks\base.py", line 402, in __eq__
    return (self.name == other.name) and (self.deconstruct() == other.deconstruct())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtailmodelchooser\blocks.py", line 41, in deconstruct
    kwargs['target_model'] = self.target_model._meta.label_lower
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtailmodelchooser\blocks.py", line 24, in target_model
    return resolve_model_string(self._target_model)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailcore\utils.py", line 45, in resolve_model_string
    return apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 205, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 172, in get_model
    "App '%s' doesn't have a '%s' model." % (self.label, model_name))
LookupError: App 'team_rooster' doesn't have a 'spieler' model.
```

I tried to do the migration before commenting out the part of the code where the text "`spieler`" is present, but I still have a error.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the error, so that we know what line it's coming from.

Comment: I added full error trace as you said @gasman

Comment: Please try deleting the migration file that was previously created with `./manage.py makemigrations` (i.e. the highest-numbered file in team_rooster/migrations/), and then re-run `./manage.py makemigrations`. I can't see anything in your models.py which would cause this, so I suspect you've already fixed the error, and now need to rebuild the migration file.

Comment: thanks @gasman that solve my problem with makemigrations, but i got another, that i tried before and didn't find solution. I'll open new question

Answer (score 0):

Delete the migration file that was previously created with `./manage.py makemigrations` and re-run `./manage.py makemigrations`

**see in the comments**